# JQuery - I need to check if a button was clicked

Tags: jquery

I need to check if a button was clicked so you can make a condition with "if"

PS: There are infinitely many elements, each with a knob. Verification should be dynamic

*My Button Event:*

```
$(btnClose).click(function () {
     $(this).parent().remove();
     $("#modalProperties").hide();
});
```

*My click element event:*

```
$(".clonado").live("click",function(){
     $("#modalProperties").show();
});
```

**Problem:**
The problem here is that the elements are inside a div and after remove them should I closes one modal
The problem is that this modal is opened by clicking on the element
What happens is that it opens and then closes because I clicking on the element start the action to close and the open modal.

Anyone know what can be done?

**I can  know if it is the first time you started the event?**

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated, use `.on()`

Comment: Note: you should use `.on()` so the second event would be - `$(document).on('click', '.clonado', function(){...});`. Would you be able to post a sample of your html structure?

Comment: please provide a small snipnet with the html layout. It seems the event is bubling up the DOM tree

Comment: I know that live is depreciated, but the change did not influence

Comment: I can't tell you whether or not it was *depreciated*, but it was *deprecated* in 1.7 and removed entirely in 1.9.

Comment: Can I stop the click event?

Comment: This sounds like a propagation issue, or something to resolve with `.one()`, however without the HTML or a jsFiddle, it's ambiguous.

Comment: @user2403131, as others have commented, we'd love to help you, but we can't until you **post your html**.

Comment: My code is very large and quite complex, which is necessary to cancel the event "click" when you click in the "link-remover"

Comment: @user2403131, just post the parts of the html that are relevant to this.  Without it, we can only guess. With it, you'll probably see several correct answers within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is to do with bubbling, fix it like this:

```
$(btnClose).click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().remove();
     $("#modalProperties").hide();
});
```

and

```
$(".clonado").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#modalProperties").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .on event and also use .ready event like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $(btnClose).on('click',function () {
   $(this).parent().remove();
   $("#modalProperties").hide();
 });

 $(document).on("click",".clonado",function(){
   $("#modalProperties").show();
 });

});
```